# html5 hide and unhide div elements

Tags: html, css, asp.net-mvc, bootstrap-5

Consider the following code

```
@using App.Models
@model App.Models.AllPeopleViewModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}
<html>
<head>

</head>
<body>
@foreach (Customer person in Model.Content)
{
<div class="card border-primary text-center">

    <div class="card-body">
        <h5 class="card-title">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => person.name)</h5>
        <p class="card-text">
            @Html.DisplayFor(x => person.houseNameOrNumber), @Html.DisplayFor(x => person.Street),
            @Html.DisplayFor(x => person.Town), @Html.DisplayFor(x => person.PostCode)
        </p>
       <div class="visually-hidden" id="call_button"></div><a href="tel:713-992-0916" class="btn btn-primary">Call Them</a>
    </div>
    <div class="card-footer text-muted">
        Identifier - @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => person.identifier)
    </div>
</div>

}
</body>
</html>
```

Specifically the line

```
<div class="visually-hidden" id="call_button"></div><a href="tel:713-992-0916" class="btn btn-primary">Call Them</a>
```

I'm trying to hide this button.  I've tried this, I've tried d.none, but neither of them work.  Bootstrap cdn is included in my layout page and working, I know this as the cards are displaying correectly, but nothing hides that button!  I want to be able to "unhide" it later on via javascript.  I also want the hidden element to not effect the rendering of the page, untill I unhide it, if that makes sense!

Thanks you in advance, this one is driving me mental!

Comment: I think the problem might be with the markup. The `visually-hidden` div ends before the `<a>`, meaning that if you add class `d-none` to the `<div>, `you are hiding and empty div, while the `<a>` is still visible.

Comment: Howling obvious, once you point it out!  I can no longer see the button, but the space it would have occupied is still there, just empty.  Is there a way to hide and unhide it, without that empty space?

Comment: I guess you mean it happens with the `visually-hidden`? That's because `visually-hidden` only hides the element but it still occupies space, for example useful for elements that only should be visible for screen readers. To completely remove it, you have to use the `d-none` class.

Comment: If you make this an answer, I'll happily accept it :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is within the markup, currently the markup is:

```
<div class="visually-hidden" id="call_button">

</div>
<a href="tel:713-992-0916" class="btn btn-primary">Call Them</a>
```

Meaning you are hiding an empty `<div>`. To hide the `<a>`, it should be inside the `.visually-hidden <div>`.

Also, the `visually-hidden` class only makes the element invisible but it still occupies space (can be useful for elements that only should be visible for screen readers). To completely hide it, use the `d-none` (or `display: none;`) class instead. Not related to Bootstrap but more information about `visibility: hidden;` vs `display: none;`: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/what-is-the-difference-between-visibilityhidden-and-displaynone/